# Проблема с демонстрацией экрана в Discord на Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, discord

Сегодня решил обновить Ubuntu 20.04 до версии 22.04. Всё прошло нормально, система работает быстро и плавно, но есть одна проблема: при моей демонстрации всего экрана в дискорде отображается только черный экран и курсор. В версии 20.04 такой проблемы не было, у меня достаточно новый ноутбук с видеокартами AMD (встроенная (AMD Radeon Vega 8) и дискретная (AMD Radeon RX 560X)) и процессором AMD, драйверов я не устанавливал. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как избавиться от этой проблемы?

Comment: Сеанс X11 или Wayland?

Comment: Я хотел переустановить Ubuntu 22.04, но у меня не очень получалось записать образ на флешку. AppImage Etcher'а не запускался, я установил libfuse2, как меня просила система, но проблема осталась. Решил разметить флешку через dd, зайти в boot manager и переустановить, но перед этим проверить сессию по вашему совету. Сделал log out, появилась пустая консоль, и я своими нетерпеливыми руками полез к кнопке питания, чтобы вырубить ноут. Он вырубился, но теперь при включении не запускается графика, есть только консоль tty1. Перед всем этим получалось записать образ, но boot manager не видел флешку

Comment: Я переустановил систему, но так и осталась проблема в Discord. Если нажать на кнопку шестерёнки, там высвечивалось, что по умолчанию выбрано Ubuntu, есть ещё вариант Ubuntu on Xorg.

Comment: Сейчас сеанс Wayland

Comment: Перейдите на Xorg?

Comment: Ничего плохого от этого не случится?

Comment: Новая убунта же перешла на Wayland